# Change multiple option with ul li

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my webshop i have multiple options, and by each option the image changes. Customers can see how it's gonna look like.

Example:

```
<label>color group 1</label>
<select>
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>

<label>color group 2</label>
<select>
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="yellow">yellow</option>
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
```

When selecting these options the image change in color. I use the following javascript for this, which automaticly adds "color1=red&" and "color2=red&" etc etc.

```
<script>
    $( "select" )
        .change(function () {
            var str = "http://www.ballonnenkoerier.nl/image/catalog/designer/image.php?product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>&",
            i = 0;
            $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
                i++;
                str += 'color' + i + '=' + $( this ).text() + '&';
            });
            str = str.replace(/&$/, '');
            $('#thumbnail').attr('src', str);
        })
    .change();
</script>
```

And the image is working like this:

```
    <img id="thumbnail" src="image/catalog/designer/image.php?product_id=50&color1=red&color2=yellow&color3=blue&" title="image" alt="image" />
```

My question:

I want to make another dropdown list (which is more friendly, because i can show the colors, using the < ul >< li > lists, but then the javascript doesn't work anymore.

Is there a possibility to change the javascript for using this method?

I have put this in a JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/j0dv6ywe/

I hope someone have the answer for me!!

Comment: post UL Li code as a fiddle what you are trying to do using ul li so that can understand a bit more....

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your list looks something like this...

```
<ul>
  <li class="red">Red</li>
  <li class="yellow">Yellow</li>
  <li class="blue">Blue</li>
</ul>
```

And you've applied styling like you suggested to show the colours.

Then you're jQuery handler could look like this...

```
$('ul li').click(function() {

 $(this).parent().find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');

 var str =  "http://www.ballonnenkoerier.nl/image/catalog/designer/image.php?product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>&",
        i = 0;
        $( "ul li.selected" ).each(function() {
            i++;
            str += 'color' + i + '=' + $( this ).text() + '&';
        });
        str = str.replace(/&$/, '');
        $('#thumbnail').attr('src', str);

});
```

Give it a try, can you see how I've tried to adapt it to your situation? Let me know if this helps or if I can help further?